# How to pass a value to Django-Modelform in InputHidden charField from the another model

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I have this form.py:

```
 from shortcut import get_timezone
 class HostCreateForm(forms.ModelForm):
     def save(self, commit=True):
         host1 = super(HostCreateForm, self).save(commit=False)
         user = request.user.username 
         host1.timezone=get_timezone(user=user)
         host1.save()
         return host1

 class Meta:
     model = Host
     widgets = {
         'user': forms.HiddenInput(),
         'timezone': forms.HiddenInput()
     }
```

  **timezone**
  is an input hidden field from Host model defined in model.py.

  **get_timezone**
  method: (definition as following)

```
 def get_timezone(user=None):
 timezone = Userprofile.objects.all()
 timezone = timezone.get(user=user)
 return timezone.timezone
```

whereas UserProfile is another model also defined in models.py which is used to store the timezone , first name and last name of a user at the time of his/her registration. My main motive is to get this default timezone from Userprofile model and pass it to that hidden input field (timezone).
I tried with the above code (host1.timezone=get_timezone(user=user) written in save method which call the get_timezone method and it should return the timezone form Userprofile model for a loginned user but it didn't work.

I think the main problem are coming with the passing the name of requesting user at the time of calling get_timezone methos from save method. I am not able to do that. From the current scenario i am getting the following error:
*global name 'request' is not defined*

Any help will be appreciable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
timezone = timezone.filter(user=user)
return timezone.timezone
```

`timezone.filter(...)` will return you a queryset, and you can not call `.timezone` on a queryset. You must get the related object by either using `get`:

```
timezone = timezone.get(user=user)
```

or by list slicing:

```
timezone = timezone.filter(user=user)[0]
```

UPDATE: Ok, i just notice it.

Problem is, you can not pass a request object to a form's `save` method. Best way to deal with the problem is doing it in your view layer.

In your view:

```
my_form = HostCreateForm(request.POST):
    if my_form.is_valid(): #do the validation
        my_inst = my_form.save(commit=False) #pass the form values to a new model instance without saving.
        my_inst.timezone = request.user.username #set the user or do whhatever you want eith the form data.
        my_inst.save() #that will call your save methhod that you override.
```

And you remove the parts that sets the user from your `save` method.

Comment: Thenx for replying Fallen. But there is another problem i am not able to pass the requesting user or loggined user to get_timezone method (see the save method). According to above definition in save method i am getting this error: global name request is not defined